# Want to include ad code after related post

Tags: theme-development, include, ads

I want to include ads HTML code after related post plugin. [My site](http://www.dewdropzone.com) my `single.php` code below:

```
            <?php if ( get_option('wap8_author_gravatar') == 'true' ) { ?>
            <div id="post-header"><!-- Begin post header -->
                <div class="post-title clear"><!-- Begin post title -->
                    <div class="header-gravatar">
                        <p><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('email'), '50' ); ?></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="header-title">
                        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End post title -->
                <div id="post-data">
                    <p><?php _e('Written by','periodic'); ?> <?php the_author(); ?>. <?php _e('Posted in','periodic'); ?> <?php the_category(', '); ?>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End post header -->

            <?php } else { ?>
            <div id="post-header-wide"><!-- Begin post header -->
                <div class="header-title">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </div>

                <div id="post-data">
                    <p><?php _e('Written by','periodic'); ?> <?php the_author(); ?>. <?php _e('Posted in','periodic'); ?> <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
                    <?php the_tags('<p>Tagged: ', ', ', '</p>'); ?>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End post header -->              
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ( get_option('wap8_post_img') == 'true' ) { ?>         
            <div id="lead-image"><!-- Begin lead image -->
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                <p><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-leadimg'); ?></p>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <p><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/thumbnails/thumbnail-leadimg.jpg" width="610" height="225" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" /></p>
            <?php } ?>
            </div><!-- End lead image -->
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="published"><!-- Begin published -->
                <p><?php _e('Published on','periodic'); ?> <?php the_time('F d, Y'); ?> <?php _e('with','periodic'); ?> <a class="scroll-it" href="#comments" title="<?php comments_number(__('No Comments','periodic'),__('1 Comment','periodic'),__('% Comments','periodic')); ?>"><?php comments_number(__('No Comments','periodic'),__('1 Comment','periodic'),__('% Comments','periodic')); ?></a></p>
            </div><!-- End published -->

            <?php if ( get_option('wap8_share_show') == 'true' ) { ?><!-- Begin posts with share column option -->              
            <div class="post-columns clear"><!-- Begin post columns -->
                <div <?php post_class( 'post-460 post-entry' ); ?>><!-- Begin post entry -->
                <?php the_content(); ?>

                <?php wp_link_pages('before=<p class="post-pager">' . __('<span>Pages:</span>', 'periodic') . '&after=</p>&next_or_number=number&pagelink=%'); ?>
                </div><!-- End post entry -->

                <div class="post-left-column"><!-- Begin post left column -->
                    <h3 class="widget-head"><?php echo( stripslashes ( get_option('wap8_share_title') ) );?></h3>
                    <ul class="share-actions">
                        <?php if ( get_option('wap8_show_twitter') == 'true' ) { ?><li><a href=<?php echo wap8_twitter_share_url(); ?> class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-via="<?php echo( stripslashes ( get_option('wap8_twitter_user') ) );?>"><?php _e( 'Tweet', 'periodic' ); ?></a></li><?php } ?>
                        <?php if ( get_option('wap8_show_su') == 'true' ) { ?><li><script src="http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=1"></script></li><?php } ?>
                        <?php if ( get_option('wap8_show_digg') == 'true' ) { ?><li><a class="DiggThisButton DiggCompact"></a></li><?php } ?>
                        <?php if ( get_option('wap8_show_gbuzz') == 'true' ) { ?><li><a title="Post to Google Buzz" class="google-buzz-button" href="http://www.google.com/buzz/post" data-button-style="small-button"></a></li><?php } ?>
                        <?php if ( get_option('wap8_show_email') == 'true' ) { ?><li><a class="share-button" href="mailto:?subject=<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>&amp;body=<?php _e('Thought you might like this:','periodic'); ?> <?php the_title_attribute(); ?> &#150; <?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php _e('Email','periodic'); ?> &#147;<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>&#148; <?php _e('to a friend','periodic'); ?>"><?php _e('Email This','periodic'); ?></a></li><?php } ?>
                        <?php if ( get_option('wap8_show_print') == 'true' ) { ?><li><a class="share-button" href="JavaScript:window.print();" title="<?php _e('Print','periodic'); ?> &#147;<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>&#148;"><?php _e('Print This','periodic'); ?></a></li><?php } ?>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- End post left column -->
            </div><!-- End post columns -->
            <?php } else { ?><!-- End post share column option -->
                <div <?php post_class( 'post-620 post-entry' ); ?>><!-- Begin post entry -->
                <?php the_content(); ?>

                <?php wp_link_pages('before=<p class="post-pager">' . __('<span>Pages:</span>', 'periodic') . '&after=</p>&next_or_number=number&pagelink=%'); ?>
                </div><!-- End post entry -->
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ( get_option('wap8_post_author') == 'true' ) { ?>
            <div id="author-box" class="clear"><!-- Begin author box -->
                <h3><?php _e('About','periodic'); ?> <?php the_author(); ?></h3>
                <div class="post-gravatar">
                    <p><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('email'), '50' ); ?></p>
                </div>
                <div id="author-text">
                    <p><?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?></p>

                    <p class="last"><?php _e('Browse Archived Articles by','periodic'); ?> <a class="right-arrow" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/author/<?php the_author_meta('user_nicename'); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php _e('Browse Archived Articles by','periodic') ?> <?php the_author(); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End author box -->
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ( get_option('wap8_post_rel') == 'true' ) { locate_template( '/includes/relatedposts.php', true, true ); } ?>

            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif ?>
        </div><!-- End left column -->

        <?php get_sidebar('right'); ?>
    </div><!-- End column container -->
</div><!-- End inner wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm absolutely guessing here, but you may want to put your code between:

```
<?php if ( get_option('wap8_post_rel') == 'true' ) { locate_template( '/includes/relatedposts.php', true, true ); } ?> // these are your related posts
```

and

```
<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?> //these are the comments
```